# Problems in using cox regression with restricted cubic spline plot with R software

Tags: line-drawing

In R software, I want to plot a graph by using cox regression with the restricted cubic spline method. However, I can't quite get it to work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
library(rms); require(rms); library(Hmisc)
d<-curve.men
dd <- datadist(d)
options(datadist="dd")
fit <- cph(Surv(time,death) ~ rcs(bmi,4)
           + systolic +glucose + l_chol + age 
           + edu_g2 + smoke_s + l_chol + drink + activity_l+activity_w,
             data=d, nk=5)
plot(Predict(fit,bmi), xlab="bmi", ylab="Relative Risk", lty=1, lwd=2)
```

Which creates the following plot **(A)**:

[image]

However, I want to plot the following graph **(B)**:

[image]

1. How do I set the reference point? (for example: `bmi = 24.21429` as the reference point)
2. I want to add the horizontal line. I tried using `abline(h=1)`, but it did not work.
3. All in all, how do I make the graph look like (B)?

Comment: in graph (A), y range is   -1.0 ~ 1.5,

Comment: Welcome to Computer Graphics SE! I tried to improve the readability of your post a bit. However, I'm not sure it's a great fit for this site. You could probably just ask this on [so] instead. I've [started a discussion on meta](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/205/16) whether questions about plotting simple graphs are considered on topic or not.

Comment: Given that this is specifically about R, it's likely a better fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: After discussion, the consensus seems to be that questions about plotting are off-topic. https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/are-questions-about-plotting-graphs-on-topic